# Check if a string is XML formatted

Tags: ruby, xml, string

I'm wondering if there's a function in Ruby like `is_xml?(string)` to identify if a given string is XML formatted.

Comment: Do you want to differentiate between XML and properly formed HTML?

Comment: Hi Tin Man, the answer is no. I have some common strings and XML formatted strings mixed together. I want to split them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nokogiri's `parse` uses a simple regex test looking for `<html>` in an attempt to determine if the data to be parsed is HTML or XML:

```
string =~ /^s*<[^Hh>]*html/ # Probably html
```

Something similar, looking for the XML declaration would be a starting point:

```
string = '<?xml version="1.0"?><foo><bar></bar></foo>'
string.strip[/\A<\?xml/]
=> "<?xml"
```

If that returns anything other than `nil` the string contains the XML declaration. It's important to test for this because an empty string will fool the next steps.

```
Nokogiri::XML('').errors.empty?
=> true
```

Nokogiri also has the `errors` method, which will return an array of errors after attempting to parse a document that is malformed. Testing that for any size would help:

```
Nokogiri::XML('<foo>').errors
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag foo line 1>]
Nokogiri::XML('<foo>').errors.empty?
=> false

Nokogiri::XML(string).errors.empty?
=> true
```

would be true if the document is syntactically valid.

---

I just tested Nokogiri to see if it could tell the difference between a regular string vs. true XML:

```
[2] (pry) main: 0> doc = Nokogiri::XML('foo').errors
[
    [0] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found>
]
```

So, you can loop through your files and sort them into XML and non-XML easily:

```
require 'nokogiri'

[
  '',
  'foo',
  '<xml></xml>'
].group_by{ |s| (s.strip > '') && Nokogiri::XML(s).errors.empty? }
=> {false=>["", "foo"], true=>["<xml></xml>"]}
```

Assign the result of `group_by` to a variable, and you'll have a hash you can check for non-XML (`false`) or XML (`true`).

Comment: Great! The details are really helpful.

Comment: I added a bit more code you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function in Ruby's String class or Active Support's String extensions, but you can use Nokogiri to [detect errors in XML](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/ensuring_well_formed_markup.html):

```
begin
  bad_doc = Nokogiri::XML(badly_formed) { |config| config.strict }
rescue Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError => e
  puts "caught exception: #{e}"
end
```

Comment: This doesn't tell us much: `Nokogiri::XML('') { |config| config.strict }
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x3fc9ba1c9a1c name="document">`. An empty string isn't XML, nor is it correctly or incorrectly formatted. `Nokogiri::XML('').errors` will tell you if there are errors, but more clearly.

Comment: @theTinMan right, the link has an example of .errors usage as well. `puts bad_doc.errors`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now  I know what to do~